# How to keep stuff when you die in Terraria

Tags: terraria

When I die, I lose all the things I worked for. 
I've seen the YouTube videos where they remain with the player. 
How can I set up Terraria so that my inventory persists when I die?

Answer (score 11):

When creating the character, select *softcore* difficulty. You will still drop half of the coins you're carrying, but you will keep all your items.

[image: Softcore]

If it says something else than softcore above "Create", click it and you should be able to select from three different options:

[image: Select difficulty]

Hovering over the option will show you what happens when you die.

Comment: IIRC, Mediumcore makes it so you only drop (part of) your money. That's what I play on.

Comment: @RobertRose mediumcore makes you drop all items (not sure about coins) on death

Comment: softcore is the one where you drop half your money on death, and that's it. mediumcore you drop everything (including all coins), and hardcore you drop everything and are dead for good.

Comment: It seems you're correct, OP, you're going to want softcore.